# Сопоставить dataframe с разным периодом

Tags: python

Есть два датафрейма:

```
          Date   value1 value2 
0   2017-01-03       60     70
1   2017-01-04       63     75
2   2017-01-05       61     71
3   2007-01-08       62     75
4   2017-04-13       53     57
5   2017-04-14       51     59
6   2017-04-15       57     52
7   2017-04-16       53     53
```

Второй:

```
         Date       Time    var
0   4/13/2017   19:40:00    147
1   4/13/2017   19:41:00    146
2   4/13/2017   19:42:00    148
3   4/13/2017   19:43:00    142
4   4/13/2017   19:44:00    147
5   4/13/2017   19:45:00    142
6   4/13/2017   19:46:00    142
7   4/13/2017   19:47:00    144
8   4/13/2017   19:48:00    148
9   4/13/2017   19:49:00    140
```

Как их слить вместе, чтобы получить, чтобы значение `value1` `value2` от дней заполняли столбцы с минутками:

```
         Date       Time    var value1 value2
0   4/13/2017   19:40:00    147     53     57
1   4/13/2017   19:41:00    146     53     57
2   4/13/2017   19:42:00    148     53     57
3   4/13/2017   19:43:00    142     53     57
4   4/13/2017   19:44:00    147     53     57
5   4/13/2017   19:45:00    142     53     57
6   4/13/2017   19:46:00    142     53     57
7   4/13/2017   19:47:00    144     53     57
8   4/13/2017   19:48:00    148     53     57
9   4/13/2017   19:49:00    140     53     57
```

Как видно, некоторых дат может не быть в минутках а может и днях.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поменять формат у колонки с датой в первой таблице и воспользоваться функцией merge. Она по дефолту отработает по одноименным колонкам

```
 df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d') \
                 .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y').str.lstrip("0")

        Date  value1  value2
0  1/03/2007      60      70
1  1/04/2007      63      75
...


df2.merge(df1)

        Date      Time  var  value1  value2
0  4/13/2017  19:40:00  147      53      57
1  4/13/2017  19:41:00  146      53      57
2  4/13/2017  19:42:00  148      53      57
3  4/13/2017  19:43:00  142      53      57
4  4/13/2017  19:44:00  147      53      57
5  4/13/2017  19:45:00  142      53      57
6  4/13/2017  19:46:00  142      53      57
7  4/13/2017  19:47:00  144      53      57
8  4/13/2017  19:48:00  148      53      57
9  4/13/2017  19:49:00  140      53      57
```